# Rails beginner - comparison of Time with nil failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through this Blogger tutorial [http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i3:-tagging](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i3%3a-tagging)

and I keep getting the "comparison of Time with nil failed" error when I add

```
<p>Posted <%=distance_of_time_in_words(comment.article.created_at, comment.created_at) %> later<p>
```

to my Comment's partial (_comments.html.erb)

Here's my schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140618233420) do

  create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "author_name"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id"

 end
```

Can someone explain? My rails server indicates that both the comments and articles have timestamps so how are they showing up as nil?

Here is the full code in my _comment.html.erb file

```
<div>
    <h4>Comment by <%= comment.author_name %></h4>
    <p class="comment"><%= comment.body %></p>
    <p>Posted <%=distance_of_time_in_words(comment.article.created_at, comment.created_at) %> later<p>

</div>
```

Here's my controller code:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
        @comment.article_id = params[:article_id]

        @comment.save

        redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
    end

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:author_name, :body)
    end
end
```

Comment: How you are using `comment` in the code? Is `comment` an instance variable of `Comment`.Please post the full code of your `_comments.html.erb`

Comment: Thanks ... I just posted it above.

Comment: Is comment.article nil per chance?

Comment: perhaps you can use t.timestamps instead of 2 t.datetime declarations in the migrations. Search for t.timestamps in the page you've referenced here.

Comment: If you open your `rails console` and do: `Comment.last.article_id` - does it work?

Comment: yup. It says, 14 ... which I assume is the id.

Comment: Just for debugging: remove the `distance_of_time_in_words` method and just write `<%= comment.article.created_at %>`

Comment: Can you post the file in which the `_comments.html.erb` is rendered? And also post the related controller code.

Comment: @Pavan I just posted it above.

Comment: In the same page as the `distance_of_time_in_words`, replace this function by a simple `<%= "Article created_at: #{comment.article.created_at} Comment created_at: #{comment.created_at} %>` to see if there is actually a value returned for both records

Comment: Could it have been that there was no space after the = sign in the function? If so, I just fixed that and now I'm getting more SyntaxError in Article Controller message that I'm gunna try to figure out. Anyway ... thanks everyone for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is included in your code:

```
<%= render partial: 'articles/comment', collection: @article.comments %>
```

**/models/comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Comment: I have all of that and it works - the comments form shows up if I delete the distance_of_time_in_words line.